# Meaning of Depth First Search on certain edges?

Tags: depth-first-search

I understand depth first search on a graph, but I'm having difficulty understanding what it means to do depth first search on *only certain edges*.  If given an undirected graph, with 2 types of edges, ordinary edges, and *required* edges, then apparently according to the resource below it's possible to do depth first search on the required edges:

*To generate all feasible columns for the problem, we use a depth-first search on the
required edges. The search path is broken when no required edge can be added.*

Here's the paper: https://shorturl.at/hyE45.  The relevant part is section 2.1.

The reason this doesn't make sense to me is because the routes must start and end at a depot node.  So, creating a route using depth first search *on the required edges* doesn't make sense, since the route isn't guaranteed to return to the depot node, unless we add ordinary edges.  What is the meaning of depth first search in this context?